# Usage of re.I in Python re.split

Tags: python, regex

I have code that goes

```
s = 'fwerewkrewjrcl23QWERCSHSAesew'
print s

print re.split(r'[a-f]', s)
print re.split(r'[a-f]', s,re.IGNORECASE)
print re.split(r'[a-fA-F]', s)
```

Now, for the first one, I got the answer I expected :

`['', 'w', 'r', 'wkr', 'wjr', 'l23QWERCSHSA', 's', 'w']`

But the second one is giving me this:

`['', 'w', 'rewkrewjrcl23QWERCSHSAesew']`

when I expected to see this:
`['', 'w', 'r', 'wkr', 'wjr', 'l23QW', 'R', 'SHS', '', 's', 'w']`

I get the expected output only when I execute the third split.  I thought the second and the third were equivalent.   What am I missing?   I saw the docs and other sites for clarification but couldn't find any.   I also saw a YouTube video where the presenter seemed to unexpectedly run into this as well but glossed over it.

Comment: Thanks!   Is there an FAQ where I can go Python-->re-->re.split and find the questions listed there?

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split

> re.**split**(*pattern*, *string*, *maxsplit*=0, *flags*=0)

Your `re.I` (= 2) is passed as `maxsplit`, so the effect is the string is split 2 times at most. Use [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) to pass it to `flags`.

```
print re.split(r'[a-f]', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
#                           ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks!   Kicking myself for not checking the usage...